# MongoDB create $lookup on multipe document with LIKE condition

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Suppose I have 2 documents and I want to make join.

**customers** document

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596d5aacb02f922a92475698"),
    "code" : "A001",
    "name" : "NameA001",
    "age" : 35
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596d5aacb02f922a9247569a"),
    "code" : "A002",
    "name" : "NameA002",
    "age" : 52
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596d5aacb02f922a9247569c"),
    "code" : "A003",
    "name" : "NameA003",
    "age" : 47
}
```

**sale** document

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596d5ad3b02f922a924756c3"),
    "ucode" : "SL-A001",
    "pname" : "Product 1",
    "quantity" : 3
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596d5ad3b02f922a924756c5"),
    "ucode" : "SL-A001",
    "pname" : "Product 2",
    "quantity" : 5
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596d5ad3b02f922a924756cd"),
    "ucode" : "SL-A002",
    "pname" : "Product 3",
    "quantity" : 10
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596d5ad3b02f922a924756d1"),
    "ucode" : "SL-A003",
    "pname" : "Product 8",
    "quantity" : 5
}
```

I want to make join on customers and sale document to get all customers whose age are less than 50. The result looks like

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596d5aacb02f922a92475698"),
    "code" : "A001",
    "name" : "NameA001",
    "age" : 35,
    "history" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("596d5ad3b02f922a924756c3"),
            "ucode" : "SL-A001",
            "pname" : "Product 1",
            "quantity" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("596d5ad3b02f922a924756c5"),
            "ucode" : "SL-A001",
            "pname" : "Product 2",
            "quantity" : 5
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("596d5aacb02f922a9247569c"),
    "code" : "A003",
    "name" : "NameA003",
    "age" : 47,
    "history" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("596d5ad3b02f922a924756d1"),
            "ucode" : "SL-A003",
            "pname" : "Product 8",
            "quantity" : 5
        }
    ]
}
```

I wrote aggregate statement but I dont know how to make LIKE condition on $lookup.

```
db.customer.aggregate([
   {
      $match: { "age": { $lt: 50 } }
   },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "sale",
            localField: "code",
            foreignField: "ucode",
            as: "history"
        }
   }
])
```

How can I write lookup with Like condition on localField or foreignField? (Or any suggestion to join with like condition)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `$match` comes **after** the `$lookup` and since you called the field `"history"` where the results go, then it's now `"history.age"` by it's new joined path. But you also want `$unwind` in between. When learning. Run each aggregation pipeline stage **one at a time**. And see what the output looks like as you add each stage.

Comment: Look at [How to join to two additional collections with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44960412/2313887) for a bit more depth into why you `$lookup -> $unwind -> $match` as the best pattern for doing this.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn but my question is different,
I mean, how to join by lookup with code and ucode attribute,
but code has data like "A001", ucode has data like "SL-A001"

Comment: I do $match first because I want to reduce the number of records before executing lookup, one way to make performance tuning.

Comment: Perfectly fine to `$match` first. But the point is to `$match` "after" the `$lookup`. There are plenty of examples how to do that and I just pointed you at one that also explains the usage pattern. I'm kind of left with the impression you did little more than "glance". Not providing you with code to "copy/paste", but something to actually learn from. If you read it fully you might just understand what to do. At least there's that hope