# Using results from $project gives exceeding maximum document size

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have 2 collections, say A and B.

Example A:

```
[
    {"Account": "99", "Cat_1": "Losses",  "Cat_2": "Marketing"},
    {"Account": "89", "Cat_1": "Losses",  "Cat_2": "Consultancy"},
    {"Account": "79", "Cat_1": "Losses",  "Cat_2": "Marketing"},
    {"Account": "69", "Cat_1": "Losses",  "Cat_2": "Consultancy"},
    {"Account": "59", "Cat_1": "Profits", "Cat_2": "Marketing"},
    {"Account": "49", "Cat_1": "Profits", "Cat_2": "Consultancy"},
    {"Account": "29", "Cat_1": "Profits", "Cat_2": "Marketing"},
    {"Account": "00", "Cat_1": "Profits", "Cat_2": "Consultancy"}
...
]
```

Example B:

```
[
    {"Name": "Example A", "Year": 2014, "Account": "99", "Amount": -5000},
    {"Name": "Example A", "Year": 2015, "Account": "99", "Amount": -5000},
    {"Name": "Example A", "Year": 2014, "Account": "89", "Amount": -2000},
    {"Name": "Example A", "Year": 2015, "Account": "79", "Amount": -3000},
    {"Name": "Example A", "Year": 2014, "Account": "69", "Amount": 0},
    {"Name": "Example A", "Year": 2015, "Account": "59", "Amount": 100},
    {"Name": "Example A", "Year": 2016, "Account": "49", "Amount": 5000},
    {"Name": "Example A", "Year": 2014, "Account": "29", "Amount": 4000},
    {"Name": "Example A", "Year": 2015, "Account": "00", "Amount": 900},
    {"Name": "Example B", "Year": 2013, "Account": "99", "Amount": -500},
    {"Name": "Example B", "Year": 2011, "Account": "89", "Amount": -10000},
    ...
]
```

Now I want, for example, to fetch all "Cat_1" accounts with their type to end up with this:

```
[
    {"cat": "Losses",  "Accounts": ["99", "89", "79", "69"]},
    {"cat": "Profits", "Accounts": ["59", "49", "29", "00"]}
]
```

Alternatively I would fetch `Cat_n` for some category and get a likewise result.

Next I unwind the Accounts and perform a lookup on collection B. This is where things go wrong and the maximum document size is exceeded. I should mention that I am only interested in 1 utiliser at a time, so my lookup looks like this at the moment:

```
...
{
  "$lookup": {
    "from": "collection_B",
    "localField": "Account",
    "foreignField": "Account",
    "as": "results"
  }
},
{
  "$addFields": {
    "results": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$results",
        "as": "comp",
        "cond": {
          "$eq": [
            "$$results.Name", "Example A"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
...
```

After the lookup I use `$addFields` to overwrite the original results field, as most of them I don't want because I'm only interested in specific utilisers.

There are around 10M documents in the second collection, roughly 300k per utiliser. So after this lookup there are never more than those 300k in the result. When requesting the `cat_1` categories the result will be two arrays "Losses" and "Profits" which both contain roughly 800 accounts.

I reduce the document sizes with `$project` to only include fields I actually want. Additionally I also use `$match` as early as possible to eliminate unwanted documents from the aggregation.

It's all not helping though, the document keeps growing beyond the 16MB BSON limit. Only when using `$limit` with a rather low value of ±300 the result will be returned and is missing information.

What I'm ultimately interested in is generating a documents that contain something like this for a given utiliser and `Cat_n`

```
{
  "Name": "Example A",
  "Losses": [
    {"Year": 2014, "Amount": ...},
    {"Year": 2015, "Amount": ...},
    {"Year": 2016, "Amount": ...}
  ],
  "Profits": [
    {"Year": 2014, "Amount": ...},
    {"Year": 2015, "Amount": ...},
    {"Year": 2016, "Amount": ...}
  ],
}
```

I've been thinking of just creating two separate aggregations, one for getting the categories and 1 for aggregating the results from collection B. But I'd have to check each document to find out to which category it belongs, which doesn't seem terribly efficient.
Alternatively, I could create a third collection where I merge the documents from both collections and do my aggregates there, but if possible I'd rather avoid this as it adds extra complexity in maintaining or reviewing this data at a later point.

Comment: Did you look to this "Changed in version 2.6: The db.collection.aggregate() method returns a cursor and can return result sets of any size. Previous versions returned all results in a single document, and the result set was subject to a size limit of 16 megabytes" https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

Comment: @DanieleTassone, interesting feature! While it didn't solve my problem now, I have a feeling I might use it somewhere down the line

Answer (score -1):

I found that the array of matches returned by $lookup was exceeding the BSON limit of 16MB. Because of this it is was not possible to retrieve the results in any way.

Managed to solve it by reversing the logic, I'm now performing a lookup from collection B in A. This actually makes way more sense as I can now filter away 94% of documents before performing a lookup, in stead of having to do this after.

Comment: Sounds more like a "workaround" than a solution. The correct thing to do is to actually `$unwind` and `$match` directly following a `$lookup`. The reason is those two pipeline stages actually become part of the `$lookup` stage. The result is you only get the data back that your conditions ask for and since its "unwound" it's not possible to break the 16MB limit. You need to look at the "explain" output to see the actual effect on the pipeline. I give a lot more detail on https://stackoverflow.com/a/44960412/2313887. So you can do the same thing the other way around.